# file_get_html how enable cookies

Tags: php, cookies

```
$url ="www.site.com"
$request = array('http' => array('user_agent' => 'UserAgent/1.0'));                 
$context = stream_context_create($request);     
$html = file_get_html($url, false, $context);
```

how do in `$request` I enable to be saved cookies from the site `$url`?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, would be pretty insecure if you could easily read another user's cookies from certain websites..

Comment: and if I go to curl $url then how do I get DOM object?

Answer (score 1):

Ref : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

and did some modify to use file_get_html

```
<?php
$url ="www.site.com";
// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n".
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n")`enter code here`
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_html($url, false, $context);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for trivial answer, but you can't.

Answer (score 0):

you can't - for cookie handling use curl otherwise you are responsible for saveing and re-useing cookies from and within a request.

in curl you can use the options `COOKIEJAR` and `COOKIEFILE`

```
$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('User-Agent: UserAgent/1.0'));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```